# Theme unit test data Foreign fonts come in garbled on my machine

Tags: theme-development, unit-tests

Having just tried out the Theme Unit Test Data from the WordPress.org Codex, I noticed that some of the body text doesn't import properly on my set up which is a Mac running Mavericks.

The effect is particularly noticeable on the Lorem ipsum page where non latin characters just arent rendering at all being replaced by nonsense characters. I was following a tutorial on how to make a theme framework on the tuts plus website. Is there an import setting that I am failing to notice or is it some other setting?

My charset is defined as

```
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
```

How ever I dont believe this is having any effect since if I copy and paste the characters into the post, they appear ok.

Can anyone shed any light on this?